# Where can I find the authentication code section in Sylius?

Tags: authentication, symfony, passwords, sylius

I need to add some operations at the moment when the users try to login in my Sylius website.
For example, I want to let the admin know the login events when the password checking process is triggered.

So, I tried to find the authentication process in the Sylius project code, but I haven't find it yet.

I want to ask for the Sylius/Symfony experts to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sylius is using Symfony security bundle for authentication, so you can use [Authentication Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#authentication-events).

For example, if you want to log failed login attempts, you can simply create new [EventSubscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber), subscribe `LoginFailureEvent` and execute your logic here.